# SVG image is found by JQuery offset method, but width & height values are set to 0

Tags: jquery, web, svg

Im doing application, which draws some components on web with usage of SVG. But when application is looking for drawn SVG image, it's found, left and top values are found, but its height and width is 0. Why?

Code:

```
pointA = $('.connectionPoint[data-selector="' + selector + '"]');
aOffset = pointA.offset();
x1 = aOffset.left;
y1 = aOffset.top;
console.log("After scroll top: x1=" + x1 + ", y1=" + y1 + ", w=" + pointA.outerWidth() + ",h=" + pointA.outerHeight());
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because an `<svg>` element's `width` and `height` attributes are different from HTML's.  They are not defined the same way in the DOM and jQuery is only designed to handle HTML elements.

You will either need to write your own method to read the SVG's width and height (eg. `mysvg.width.baseVal.value` or `mysvg.getAttribute("width")`), or wrap your `<svg>` in a `<div>` so jQuery can read its width and height instead.